# In rc low or high pass filter how to calculate cut-off frequency when a r is connected in parallel to c in low pass filter

Tags: circuit-analysis

In rc low pass filter how to calculate cut-off frequency when a r is connected in parallel to c.[image]

here vac=1v(p-p) f=1khz,r1=r2=1Mohm,c=1mf,v=5v

Comment: For AC analysis, treat all DC voltage sources as grounds. After all, they have no AC voltage, right?

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the DC source?
Regarding your question: You have nothing to do than to apply the DEFINITION of the cut-off frequency wc:

1.) Set the magnitude of the transfer function equal to Ao/SQRT(2) with Ao being the transfer function value for w=0. The value of Ao can be derived from the circuit by visual inspection neglecting the capacitor (1/wC approacing infinite).

2.) Alternative: Equalize the real and imag. parts of the complex tranfer function .

Comment: Here I wanted o find out the voltage vs time graph across the capacitor.but the 2 resistors and a cap is there.so how to get the cut-off frequency to plot the curve

Comment: Didn`t I gave you some instructions above?